# Bundle Issues in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, bundle, onclicklistener

Running into an error when trying to put my bundle into my intent in an `onClickListener()` inside a `RecyclerView` `CustomViewHolder`.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.os.Bundle.putString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a
>   null object reference

I've also attempted to create a new bundle rather than using the extras, but get the same error as above. Oddly enough the `putExtras()` way works fine with one variable, passes across correctly, but alas I have about 8 different variables to insert for the secondary page.

Code is as follows:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
    intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), CardActivity.class);
    extras = intent.getExtras();
        extras.putString(CARD_IMG, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImg());
        extras.putString(CARD_FLAVOR, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getFlavor());
        extras.putString(CARD_TEXT, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText());
        extras.putString(CARD_TYPE, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getType());
        extras.putString(CARD_ARTIST, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getArtist());
        extras.putString(CARD_SET, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getCardSet());
        extras.putString(CARD_RARITY, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getRarity());
        extras.putString(CARD_NAME, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName());
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Any help or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks ahead of time!

Edit: I've included the full file below incase that helps. Thanks for the responses so far guys, greatly appreciated.

```
    public class RecyclerAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdaptor.CustomViewHolder> {
//for bundle keys
private static final String CARD_FLAVOR = "CARD_FLAVOR";
private static final String CARD_TYPE = "CARD_TYPE";
private static final String CARD_ARTIST = "CARD_ARTIST";
private static final String CARD_SET = "CARD_SET";
private static final String CARD_RARITY = "CARD_RARITY";
private static final String CARD_NAME = "CARD_NAME";
private static final String CARD_IMG = "CARD_IMG";
private static final String CARD_TEXT = "CARD_TEXT";

private static Intent intent;
public static Bundle extras;
public static CardList cardList;

public RecyclerAdaptor(CardList cardList) {
    this.cardList = cardList;
}

@Override
//Number of Items
public int getItemCount() {
    return cardList.Basic.size();
}


@Override
public RecyclerAdaptor.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_row, parent, false);
    CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdaptor.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Card card = cardList.Basic.get(position);
    String cost = "0";
    // Could have made values protected in class, but meh
    holder.cardName.setText(card.getName());
    holder.cardText.setText(card.getText());
    holder.cardFlavor.setText(card.getFlavor());

    // Handles dust value of card
    if (card.getRarity() != null) {
        switch (card.getRarity()) {
            case "Common": cost = "40";
                break;
            case "Rare": cost = "100";
                break;
            case "Epic": cost = "400";
                break;
            case "Legendary": cost = "1600";
                break;
        }
    }

    holder.cardCost.setText(cost);
    Picasso.with(holder.cardImg.getContext()).load(card.getImg()).into(holder.cardImg);

}

public static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView cardName;
    private TextView cardText;
    private TextView cardFlavor;
    private TextView cardCost;
    private GifImageView cardImg;
    private Button moreButton;

    public CustomViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardTitle);
        cardText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardText);
        cardFlavor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardFlavor);
        cardCost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dustTextView);
        cardImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImgView);
        moreButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.moreButton);

        moreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Clicked:" + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), CardActivity.class);
                extras = intent.getExtras();
                if(extras == null){
                    extras = new Bundle();
                }
                    extras.putString(CARD_IMG, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImg());
                    extras.putString(CARD_FLAVOR, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getFlavor());
                    extras.putString(CARD_TEXT, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText());
                    extras.putString(CARD_TYPE, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getType());
                    extras.putString(CARD_ARTIST, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getArtist());
                    extras.putString(CARD_SET, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getCardSet());
                    extras.putString(CARD_RARITY, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getRarity());
                    extras.putString(CARD_NAME, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName());
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

Complete error is as follows:

> 01-29 12:32:07.961 3030-3030/com.venaseph.hearthlopedia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.venaseph.hearthlopedia, PID: 3030
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.venaseph.hearthlopedia/com.venaseph.hearthlopedia.CardActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
>                                                                                 at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
>                                                                                 at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
>                                                                                 at com.venaseph.hearthlopedia.CardActivity.getBundleValues(CardActivity.java:41)
>                                                                                 at com.venaseph.hearthlopedia.CardActivity.onCreate(CardActivity.java:33)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

In addition, if I leave everything as is and take away the intent.putExtras, it doesn't crash.

Comment: Please check if R.id.cardImgView is defined in your xml file and check too if holder.cardImg is not null.

Comment: both seem to be functioning as intended, and are included and not null

Comment: Could you please post your CardActivity? The exception occures on CardActivity.java:41...

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `intent` is `null`, replace with below code

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), CardActivity.class);
    extras = new Bundle(); //<-- so that bundle wont be null anymore
        extras.putString(CARD_IMG, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImg());
        extras.putString(CARD_FLAVOR, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getFlavor());
        extras.putString(CARD_TEXT, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText());
        extras.putString(CARD_TYPE, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getType());
        extras.putString(CARD_ARTIST, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getArtist());
        extras.putString(CARD_SET, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getCardSet());
        extras.putString(CARD_RARITY, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getRarity());
        extras.putString(CARD_NAME, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName());
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Tried this method previously, but did again to be sure. Still get this error and a crash.  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.venaseph.hearthlopedia/com.venaseph.hearthlopedia.CardActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
**Edit**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), CardActivity.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    if (extras != null) {
        extras.putString(CARD_IMG, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImg());
        extras.putString(CARD_FLAVOR, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getFlavor());
        extras.putString(CARD_TEXT, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText());
        extras.putString(CARD_TYPE, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getType());
        extras.putString(CARD_ARTIST, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getArtist());
        extras.putString(CARD_SET, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getCardSet());
        extras.putString(CARD_RARITY, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getRarity());
        extras.putString(CARD_NAME, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName());
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this as, but it just never gets into the conditional.

Comment: @Venaseph just try this

Comment: Added the full file in the original post for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

since the `bundle` is null hence the `Null Pointer Exception`.

just instantiate the `bundle` and add the values.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), CardActivity.class);
    if(extras == null){
        extras = new Bundle();
    }
    extras.putString(CARD_IMG, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImg());
    extras.putString(CARD_FLAVOR, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getFlavor());
    extras.putString(CARD_TEXT, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText());
    extras.putString(CARD_TYPE, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getType());
    extras.putString(CARD_ARTIST, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getArtist());
    extras.putString(CARD_SET, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getCardSet());
    extras.putString(CARD_RARITY, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getRarity());
    extras.putString(CARD_NAME, cardList.Basic.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName());
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Tried this as well, still get the error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.venaseph.hearthlopedia/com.venaseph.hearthlopedia.CardActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.

Comment: can u share the stacktrace of exception... edit the question and put it there.

Comment: added the full piece